# SQL Server 2016 Mobile Report Datasets Expire about 30 Days

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2016, sql-server-mobile

We are in the process of creating a suite of SQL server 2016 Reporting Services Mobile Reports for our company’s Cloud offering to customers, however, we keep running into a situation where the all datasets expire after a certain time.

We have found that all the datasets on the server seem to stop working after 30 days after they have been created and an Error message (“The data set could not be processed. There was a problem getting data from the Report Server Web Service.”) is displayed.

To resolve this, all the datasets need to be opened manually and re-saved onto the server. As you can imagine, this isn’t really a suitable solution for as we have a long number of reports and datasets for each customer.

After a bit of investigation, we have managed to pinpoint a “Snapshotdata” table in the report server database which has an “ExpirationDate” column, which seems to be linked to the issue.

Has anyone else can across this before and could please advise a possible solution to the datasets expiring? Why would the datasets have an expiration date on them anyway?

Answer (score 0):

A dataset will not be expired once it has been created.

In your scenario, did you create cache for those datasets? Was there anything change to the dataset?

You said in mobile report it prompted "dataset could not be processed" error, please locate to dataset property pane, and check whether it returns data successfully by clicking on Load Data. If not, change to another account and try again.

Besides, please check whether the account used to connect to data source was expired after 30 days which might caused the failure of data retrieval.

Comment: No cache has been set on the mobile report dataset, please see below,

http://imgur.com/a/Ulgk7

No change has been made.

No account change makes a difference.

To physically rectify this issue we have to edit and close the dataset in report builder for each individual dataset to restore its functionality.